# SQL query optimization to get result in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have below two queries by using which we can get no of Serious, Fatal accidents per month.

How can we optimize and get result in one query for diffferent accidents types?

```
SELECT 
     COUNT(ICT.ID)      NoOfAccident,    
     YEAR(ICT.[Date])   AccidentYear,
     Month(ICT.[Date])  AccidentMonth,
     MAX(ICT.[Date])  AS    AccidentDate
    FROM
    Accidents ICT   
        Where   
        ICT.AccidentType    = "Serious"
        AND 
        ICT.[Date] > CONVERT(DATETIME, '09/20/13', 1)
    Group By
    YEAR(ICT.[Date]),
    Month(ICT.[Date])
    ORDER BY
    IncidentDate ASC


SELECT 
 COUNT(ICT.ID)      NoOfAccident,    
 YEAR(ICT.[Date])   AccidentYear,
 Month(ICT.[Date])  AccidentMonth,
 MAX(ICT.[Date])  AS    AccidentDate
FROM
Accidents ICT   
    Where   
    ICT.AccidentType    = "Fatal"
    AND 
    ICT.[Date] > CONVERT(DATETIME, '09/20/13', 1)
Group By
YEAR(ICT.[Date]),
Month(ICT.[Date])
ORDER BY
IncidentDate ASC
```

How can we optimize and get result in one query like:

```
NoOfSeriousAccident
NoOfFatalAccident
AccidentYear
AccidentMonth
AccidentDate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
 ICT.AccidentType,
 COUNT(ICT.ID)      NoOfAccident,    
 YEAR(ICT.[Date])   AccidentYear,
 Month(ICT.[Date])  AccidentMonth,
 MAX(ICT.[Date])  AS    AccidentDate
FROM
Accidents ICT   
    Where   
    ICT.AccidentType IN ("Serious","Fatal")
    AND 
    ICT.[Date] > CONVERT(DATETIME, '09/20/13', 1)
Group By
ICT.AccidentType
YEAR(ICT.[Date]),
Month(ICT.[Date])
ORDER BY
IncidentDate ASC
```

EDIT: Based on updated requirement, you can use PIVOT to get separate columns for fatal and serious accident counts as follows:

```
;with pivoted as
(select 
accidentyear, 
accidentmonth, 
serious as NoOfSeriousAccident, 
fatal as NoOfFatalAccident from
(SELECT 
 ICT.AccidentType,
 COUNT(ICT.ID)    cnt,
 YEAR(ICT.[accidentdate])   AccidentYear,
 Month(ICT.[accidentdate])  AccidentMonth
FROM
Accident ICT   
Where   
ICT.AccidentType IN ('Serious','Fatal')
AND 
ICT.[accidentdate] > CONVERT(DATETIME, '09/20/13', 1)
Group By
ICT.AccidentType,
YEAR(ICT.[accidentdate]),
Month(ICT.[accidentdate])) as s

pivot
(
max(cnt) 
for accidenttype in ([serious] ,[fatal])
) as pvt
)

select 
x.accidentyear, 
x.accidentmonth,
max(a.accidentdate), 
x.NoOfSeriousAccident, 
x.NoOfFatalAccident,
from pivoted x 
inner join accident a
on month(a.accidentdate) = x.accidentmonth
and year(a.accidentdate) = x.accidentyear
group by x.accidentmonth, x.accidentyear, x.seriouscount, x.fatalcount
order by max(a.accidentdate)
```

Comment: To add more to my question we have to get result like this NoOfSeriousAccident
NoOfFatalAccident
AccidentYear
AccidentMonth
AccidentDate

Answer (score 1):

Trivial - group not only by year and month but also by AccidentType (and remove the filter of one accidedenttype per query).

THen you get 2 rows per year/month - one per accident type.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT 
     COUNT(ICT.ID)      NoOfAccident,    
     YEAR(ICT.[Date])   AccidentYear,
     Month(ICT.[Date])  AccidentMonth,
     MAX(ICT.[Date])  AS    AccidentDate,
     ICT.AccidentType As AccidentType

    FROM
    Accidents ICT   
        Where   
        ICT.AccidentType    = "Serious"
        AND 
        ICT.[Date] > CONVERT(DATETIME, '09/20/13', 1)
    Group By
    YEAR(ICT.[Date]),
    Month(ICT.[Date])
    ORDER BY
    IncidentDate ASC

UNION ALL
SELECT 
 COUNT(ICT.ID)      NoOfAccident,    
 YEAR(ICT.[Date])   AccidentYear,
 Month(ICT.[Date])  AccidentMonth,
 MAX(ICT.[Date])  AS    AccidentDate,
 ICT.AccidentType  As AccidentType
FROM
Accidents ICT   
    Where   
    ICT.AccidentType    = "Fatal"
    AND 
    ICT.[Date] > CONVERT(DATETIME, '09/20/13', 1)
Group By
YEAR(ICT.[Date]),
Month(ICT.[Date])
ORDER BY
IncidentDate ASC

)

select NoOfAccident,AccidentYear,AccidentMonth,AccidentDate,AccidentType  from CTE 
WHERE  AccidentType IN ('Fatal','Serious')
```

Comment: Hi Mohan, query result should be like this ' NoOfSeriousAccident
NoOfFatalAccident
AccidentYear
AccidentMonth
AccidentDate '

Comment: yeah then remove AccidentType from cte query be that in Where condition

Comment: Hi Mohan, I got this error when I execute inner queries   Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.